# Listing distribution groups only if smtp address exists

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server, exchange-management-shell

I'm trying to list all groups that contain a specific SMTP address in the group.  Below is the code I'm using but its outputting everything and not just the groups with the specified SMTP address:

```
$temp = Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited 
foreach ($group in $temp) 
{ 
  if (Get-DistributionGroupMember $group | select -ExpandProperty PrimarySmtpAddress`
   | ForEach-Object {$_.PrimarySmtpAddress -match "contoso.com"}) {

    Write-Output "GroupName:$group " 
    Write-Output "GroupName:$($group.PrimarySmtpAddress) "
    Write-Output "GroupMembers:" 
    Get-DistributionGroupMember $group|ft displayname,primarysmtpaddress
  }
  else 
  {
    Write-Host "null"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't work because your **if** statement just tests whether the code in the condition executes successfully, and there's no reason why it would fail for any group. There's nothing in the logic that makes the condition false if the **Foreach-Object** block doesn't find any matches. Try this:

```
foreach ($group in $temp) {
  if ((Get-DistributionGroupMember $group | %{$_.PrimarySmtpAddress}) -match 'contoso\.com') {
    [...]
```

`(Get-DistributionGroupMember $group | %{$_.PrimarySmtpAddress})` creates an array of the **PrimarySmtpAddress** properties of all the members, then the **if** condition tests whether it matches the regex (**-match** applied to an array returns an array of all elements that match, so it's true if at least one element matches, false if the array is empty).

Note, BTW, that the string to right of the **-match** operator is a *regex*, not a literal string. That's why I added the backslash. In a regex, `.` matches any single character, so `-match 'contoso.com'` would match strings like `contososcom` and `contoso?com`.

Comment: Great it worked and thank you for your explanation will certainly help me next time :-)